# object.function().function().function()....... how does this work?

Tags: c++

i have a problem understanding how c++ syntax works.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Accumulator{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Accumulator(int value){this->value=value;}
    Accumulator& add(int n){value+=n;}
    int get(){return value;};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Accumulator acc(10);
    acc.add(5).add(6).add(7); //<-----how does this work?????
    cout<<acc.get();
    return 0;
}
```

this line: acc.add(5).add(6).add(7);
does it work left to right or the other way
something like acc.add(5) first and then do add(6)
i dont get it.

result is supposed to be 28.

thanks in advance.

edit:
weird, this code gets compiled successfully without any errors on g++.
i got this code from some non-english college c++ textbook. english is not my first language.

2nd edit: i now get the desired warnings after using -Wall option.

Comment: I am not a C++ programmer, but I believe after each add call you get back a reference to the Accumulator object and call add again on this object.

Comment: I would have thought you would have to return the `this` pointer to concatenate functions like that.This page has a pretty good rundown of it http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/87-the-hidden-this-pointer/

Comment: @user2214712 Turn on your compiler's warnings and you'll see something like ‘*warning: no return statement in function returning non-void*’.

Comment: @Biffen yes i see it now after doing -Wall option.

Comment: @user2214712 Make it a habit to turn on as many warnings as you can take. It'll help you catch *a lot* of problems early. In fact, the code in your question has some UB somewhere, since I can make it print different things depending on which optimisation options I use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, but if it did, it would work left to right.  `Add` returns a reference to an `Accumulator` (it doesn't have a return value in your code, but it should probably return `*this`) so after you call

```
acc.add(5)
```

the return value is a reference to `acc`, which you can call `add` on again.

Here is a modified example with `mult` added that shows order of operations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Accumulator{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Accumulator(int value){ this->value = value; }
    Accumulator& add(int n){ value += n; return *this; }
    Accumulator& mult(int n){ value *= n; return *this; }
    int get(){ return value; };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Accumulator acc(10);
    acc.add(5).add(6).mult(7);
    cout << acc.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If it was right to left, the result would be `81`, but it is left to right and the result is `147`.

Answer (score 5):

This is called [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and is commonly seen in [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern.

Each method call (`acc.add(5)`) returns a reference or pointer upon which successive method calls (`.add(7)`) can operate on.